# How do I remove countersunk baluster screws?

Tags: stairs

How do I remove countersunk screws where the head is not accessible?  I'd like to find an easier way to do this than breaking drill bit after drill bit, trying to drill a large enough hole to pull the head end through[image: Picture showing existing countersunk screws and my crude attempt to remove these screws that are vestiges from wooden balusters]

Comment: Are you trying to replace broken balusters or are you removing all of them?

Comment: Uh, remove the board so the heads ARE accessible?

Comment: Going to echo @Ecnerwal comment.  Remove all the balusters, remove the base rail (there are screws under the dome caps that hold it down), then unscrew the screw holding the balusters.  Worst case, the base rail is screwed and glued down which would require replacing the base rail.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my baluster replacement! Which answer did you go with and how did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plug cutter to remove the screw and surrounding wood.

[image: Typical plug cutter]

Comment: You wouldn't want to use a plug cutter to make the holes.  You'd want a hole saw to make the holes, and a plug cutter to make the plugs to fill the holes!

Comment: In my experience, small hole saws tend to leave pretty jagged edges. (Could also be because I tend to get cheap hole saws though :) )

Comment: I have used plug cutters to remove many a broke off screw, then redrilled the hole and set a larger plug into it. That is if the hole wasn't already the right size for a plug.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I'd use a hole saw with a portable drill press.

[image: Small hole saw]

[image: Portable drill press]

If the hole saw leaves a rough hole, you can follow up with a larger forstner bit.

[image: Forstner bit]

Then fill the holes with plugs.  You can make them with a plug cutter, but they're cheap to buy online.

Comment: A hole saw with a center bit will skate off the broken off screw.

Comment: @TXTurner no need for a center bit, but if you use it, you could just make the hole off-center of the screw.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to this tread with my experience based upon the hole-saw recommendation above. First of all, this sucks. What would be a 3-second step to remove the spindle turns into a 3 minute step per spindle, after a run to the hardware store for a 5/8" holesaw bit you likely don't just have laying around. Remove the pilot bit from the hole saw because you can't use it with the screw in the way. Put the hole saw in a strong plug-in drill. Cordless drill won't get the job done. Use the hole saw to bore around the penetrating screw. Getting started is the hard part as the hole-saw teeth will want to dance around too much if you try to "center" the hole saw over the screw shaft, and then you will just tear up your wood. Instead, use the screw as a sort of "guide" so that the screw shaft is touching the inner wall of the hole-saw and serving as an anchor point on the outer radius of your hole-saw bit. The bit will still dance a bit but it's enough control to get the teeth to bite and then you are home-free. Drill down until the hole-saw teeth hit the screw-head and you will tell a difference in saw speed / smoke. Stop. Use a small chisel or flat-blade screwdriver and hammer to knock out some of the wood plug you just made. Loosen things up. Then grab the screw shaft with some pliers and yank out the wood plug you just made. In my case since I am putting in wrought-iron spindles using an anchoring system that requires a 3/4" hole, by using a smaller 5/8" hole-saw to perform the dental tooth-extraction technique on the phillips-head screw, you now can properly vertically align your hole to the top post and make the 3/4" hole. Or if you are going the epoxy glue route then 5/8" may be good enough. Seems to me that the home builder took a short-cut years ago and I'm paying the price for it today. Not a good way to have constructed the stairs, unless the objective was speed and low-cost. Oh, ok, makes sense now... Ugh.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grip Pliers (Vice Grip) to clamp the tip of the screw and unscrew. Thats what I would do. unless the head will get stuck as its going out the other end.

You will need to clamp the head parallel to the board so that you can get maximum torque. 
[image]